# Origine de « à bientôt », « à tantôt » et « à plus » et leur relation avec « au revoir »

Tags: étymologie, histoire, origine-ou-raison, salutations

Je voudrais savoir comment et quand *à bientôt, à tantôt, à plus* sont devenus synonymes, dans un registre familier, de *au revoir*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bon alors... on va commencer par dégager le *à plus* contraction très contemporaine du *à plus tard* très correct et qui signifie ni plus ni moins que... ce qu'il veut dire.
Les deux autres ne signifient pas précisément la même chose. Sans compter que cela dépend... dans quelle région de la francophonie on les entend.

Le tout premier historiquement: **tantôt** - (XIIe) qui signifie d'abord *aussitôt* et qui, usuel jusqu'au XVIIe va, par extension, prendre le sens de *prochainement*.
Ce sens est resté usuel en Belgique et au Québec.
L'usage moderne du français hexagonal le réserve à la même journée voire l'après midi. (Sens attesté dès le XVIIe) Mais son emploi devient connoté *populaire*.

***Bientôt*** est lui beaucoup plus tardif. Attesté au XVIe. Au sens de *promptement*. C'est bien à dire, contrairement à *tantôt*, **sans valeur de futur.**
Ce sens est maintenu dans l'usage soutenu. (=> dans l'usage soutenu, *à bientôt* **!=** *à tantôt*. ***à bientôt* = *à tout de suite***.)
Alors que le sens courant prend, à partir du XVIe, le sens d'avenir proche à partir de maintenant.
La locution *à bientôt* est attestée au XIXe (DHLF dixit).

Voilà pour le détail, en résumé et... sous réserve de confirmation par mes cousins et amis d'outre... Quiévrain ou Atlantique... je dirais que :
à partir du XIXe, dans le français hexagonal courant, en Belgique, au Québec, *à tantôt = à bientôt = à plus tard* = à... dans un avenir proche.
En français hexagonal soutenu, *à tantôt* est évité au profit d'un *à bientôt* synonyme de *à tout de suite.*

Comment: Bien d'accord, sauf pour la synonymie entre *à bientôt* et *à tout de suite*.

Comment: @Stéph : <mode_trolling>N'as-tu pas bientôt fini ?</mode_trolling> Bientôt n'a aucune valeur de futur dans l'usage soutenu (on retrouvera cette affirmation dans le DHLF). *Bientôt* = *de suite*. Mais on ne dit pas (et pouquoi ??) *à de suite*. Tout s'exagère évidemment sans nécessité et comme il a été jugé pertinent de surenchérir avec ***très** bientôt*. On a symétriquement surenchéri avec ***tout** de suite*. Donc oui! formellement tu as raison, aujourd'hui, ce serait plutôt *à **très** bientôt* qui = *à tout de suite*. Mais... comme *à de suite* se dit peu... j'ai achevé la besogne... ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt *à bientôt* désigne une période de temps beaucoup plus large que *à tout de suite*, qui va resté dans l'ordre de quelques heures, tandis que *à bientôt* peut s'étendre jusqu'à plusieurs mois !

Comment: @damadam : Ta réfutation commence mal : Non! *À bientôt* ne désigne **pas** *une période de temps*. Mais un instant.

Comment: @aCOSwt je me suis mal exprimé : *à bientôt* désigne un instant sur une période de temps beaucoup plus étendu

Comment: Complément pour l'usage propre à la Belgique "à tantôt"="à plus tard", mais ce plus tard est nécessairement dans la même journée. on peut le dire p.ex. à son conjoint en partant travailler. On peut le dire avec une intonation interrogative, pour dire au revoir tout en demandant confirmation qu'on se reverra encore avant la fin de la journée (ex: "Bon, j'y vais. - A tantôt ? -oui, je repasserai encore ce soir).

Comment: Petite précision sur le tantôt belge qui dans un autre contexte peut aussi indiquer un moment dans le passé ex: "J'ai rencontré Julien tantôt dans le métro" = "Je l'ai rencontré plus tôt dans la journée, dans le métro"

Comment: @LaurentS. *tantôt* dans le passé : En équivalent à *tout à l'heure* dans le passé proche ?. Je vais faire évoluer ma réponse. Dans cette optique. Coté Belgique, Éric Emmanuel Schmitt, vous le tenez (côté écriture) plus Belge que Français ou l'inverse ?)

Comment: Oui, en  ce qui me concerne que cela soit pour le passé ou le futur, "tantôt" est substituable à "toute à l'heure". Quant à Mr Schmitt, personnellement je l'ai toujours considéré comme un auteur français et je découvre aujourd'hui sa naturalisation pourtant pas si récente... encore une fois je me coucherai moins ignorant ce soir.